# How to delete all rows where date is older than two weeks ago using Grails' Gorm

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I am new to Gorm, and currently have a requirement where I need to delete all records older than two weeks.

Right now I am querying my table like this:

```
String query = "select a from history a where successful = :successful"

List<History> histories = History.executeQuery(query, null, [max:null, offset:null])

for (History history: histories){
   Date date1 = New Date()
   Date date2 = New Date(history.date)
   use(groovy.time.TimeCategory) {
      def duration = date1 - date2
      if (duration.days > 14){
         // delete here
      }
   }
}
```

I am certain there is a better and more efficient way to delete all records older than 14 days using gorm, I was wondering if anyone had any knowledge on how to do this? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The [GORM documentation](https://gorm.grails.org/latest/hibernate/manual/index.html#_batch_updates_and_deletes) recommends a couple of options, how about something like:

```
def twoWeeksAgo = use(TimeCategory){ new Date() - 2.weeks }

History.where{
    date < twoWeeksAgo
}.deleteAll()
```